# New queue for questions without an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, unanswered-questions

In the questions section one can find a special queue for [unanswered questions](https://mathoverflow.net/unanswered). It is for attracting more attention of the community and getting a possible answer in the future.

> Is it possible to have such a queue for questions without an accepted answer?

It seems the same philosophy that justifies the existence of a special queue for unanswered questions (i.e. the need for attracting more attention of the users to provide at least one acceptable answer in future) justifies the need for a queue dedicated to questions without an accepted answer as well because it is supposed that no answers in such questions were that satisfactory for the OP to be accepted, so they left the question open for receiving possibly better answers in future.

Answer (score 17):

This exists *almost.* There is a dedicated search-parameter `hasaccepted`.

Searching for `hasaccepted:no` will give a list of all questions with no accepted answer (including those without answer); searching for `hasaccepted:no answers:1` will give only those that have an answer yet still no accepted one. (These can be combined with other search-parameters to create lists per tag etc.)

I feel that this is sufficient and do not think that a dedicated tab is justified. Here is why:

- There are reasons other than there being no satisfactory answer for there being no accepted answer. A main one is ignorance about the feature or neglecting to use it. Another is not wishing to decide between several equally acceptable answers. Both are quite common.
- A questions only disappears from the unanswered list once at least one  answer has positive score, not as soon as it has some answer. Now, positive score is not a very high bar, but it is still something.

Details about the search feature, as mentioned by Kaveh, can be found on the help-center page on [searching](https://mathoverflow.net/help/searching) moreover the actual [search-page](https://mathoverflow.net/search) has a partial list on the side (the "advanced search tips" expand on click); this is the site to which one is taken when using the search-box at the top right.

Comment: It is a bit hard to keep all these special search keywords in mind. Is any list of them available somewhere around?

Comment: @Morteza, http://mathoverflow.net/help/searching

Comment: @Kaveh (+1) Thank you for introducing the useful page.

Comment: And note that you can exclude wiki questions from that by adding  `wiki:no`.